# Coordinate detection recording

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to make a macro detection for my php game, and I'm having a little problem with it.

Here's what I have.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.button').click(function(e){
        if(e.pageX == 0 || e.pageY ==0){
            <?php
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO clickmap (id) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['username']."')");  

    mysql_query("UPDATE clickmap SET clicks=clicks+1 WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")
     or die(mysql_error());  
?>
        }
    }); 
}); 

</script>
```

I thought it was working at first, then I noticed it records a user and adds to their clicks everytime they refresh the page, It's supposed to just record them and add to the clicks when they hit a 0 coords, does anyone know what the problem is, and a possible solution?

Help is very much appreciated :)

Updated code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.button').click(function(e){
        if(e.pageX == 0 || e.pageY ==0){

$.ajax({
    url: 'recorder.php',
});



        }
    }); 
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: Do you understand that PHP is processed on the **server**?  **Before** the HTML/JS arrives on the client's browser?  Take a look at your page source in the browser (usually Ctrl+U) to see what I mean.

Comment: ohhh, that explains it, sorry I'm new, do you know a way I can do it all in javascript or a way I can do it all in php? or jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, first off, this isn't even not working the way you think isn't.

Regardless of anything going on with your javascript, your page is going to fire off both of those mysql queries while its on the server, and thats before the javascript even gets near the user.

What you're going to need to do is cozy up to the documentation surrounding the [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function. You're going to need to put an ajax call where you have those mysql queries that point to a page containing said queries.

example

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myqueries.php',
});
```

Comment: I have little to no knowledge about ajax, would you mind showing me an example of an ajax call? and how I would use it in this situation?

Comment: updated with an ajax example.

Comment: Thank you, I added it but now, it doesn't record anything. I'll update my post with my current code? do you think you could tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: Are you getting an error or something or is it just not working? You may want to check your log files.

Comment: I think I know my problem, but I don't know how to fix it. Instead of getting the coords from  `$('.button').click` I need the coords from the entire browser/webpage. Do you know how to do that?